# Writing a file to a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm taking a CSC 110 project. I am trying use dictionaries for our assignment even though we haven't learned them yet.

I have a file of countries and how many medals they won separated by new line characters. EX:

```
Afghanistan
0
0
0
Albania
0
0
0
Algeria
0
2
0
```

Each line after the country is the medals they earned starting with gold and working its way down to bronze.

I want to take these and store them in a dictionary with the structure looking something like this. 
dict={Afghanistan: [0,0,0], Albania: [0,0,0]}

What I have :

```
olympic_stats = {}
fileIn = open('test.txt', 'r')

line = fileIn.readline()#Initialize Loop
counter = 0
while line != '':
    if counter == 4:
        counter = 0

    if counter%4 == 0:#First Pass, COUNTRY
        country_name = line.rstrip()
    elif counter%4 == 1:#Second Pass, GOLD
        gold_medals = int(line)
    elif counter%4 == 2:#Third Pass, SILVER
        silver_medals = int(line)
    else: #Fourth Pass, BRONZE
        bronze_medals = int(line)

    #update Counter
    counter += 1
    if counter == 4:
        olympic_stats[country_name] = [gold_medals, silver_medals, bronze_medals]


    line = fileIn.readline()#Update Loop
```

While this works it is nasty and over complicated. I'm trying to come up with a new way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your answer isn't super concise its not 'bad' per say. I might do something like this:

```
olympic_stats = {}
while line:
    line_str = line.rstrip()
    if line_str[0].isalpha():
        country = line_str 
        olympic_stats[country] = []

    else:
        olympic_stats[country].append(line_str)
```

Comment: I didn't know .isalpha() was something I could do. Is there an equivalent to that but for int?  I just added a update statement for the line variable and this worked perfectly.

Comment: Sure is, `isnumeric()`. see docs here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isnumeric.htm If you don't expect any malformed input you won't need to have an elif statement though. Just convert the line_str to int like you do above and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop here is pretty clumsy - you can do better. You could, for example,

- read the entire file at once into a list (using `file.readlines()`)
- count through the list four items at a time

which I have done here:

```
olympic_stats = {}
fileIn = open('test.txt', 'r')
fileLines = fileIn.readlines()
counter = 0
while counter < len(fileLines):
    country_name = fileLines[counter]
    gold_metals = fileLines[counter + 1]
    silver_metals = fileLines[counter + 2]
    bronze_metals = fileLines[counter + 3]

    olympic_stats[country_name] = [gold_medals, silver_medals, bronze_medals]
    counter += 4
```

There are more concise but *much* more complicated methods of doing this, by involving list comprehension and `numpy` or `itertools`, but those are more advanced topics and this should suffice for the time being.

While implementing this you might come up against errors when the number of lines in the file isn't easily divisible by four - I'll leave you to figure out how to fix that issue on your own, as it's a valuable learning experience and not too hard.